# PySpark: Compare two Dataframes based on common String column and generate Result Boolean withColumn()

Tags: python, join, pyspark, comparison, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes ddf_1 and ddf_2 that share a common column of stringed IDs. My goal is to create a new Boolean is_fine column in ddf_1 that contains True if the ID was contained in ddf_1 and ddf_2 or False if the ID was not contained in ddf_1 and ddf_2.

Consider this example data:

```
#### test
#example data
data_1 = { 
    'fruits': ["apples", "banana", "cherry"],
    'myid': ['1-12', '2-12', '3-13'],
    'meat': ["pig", "cow", "chicken"]}

data_2 = { 
    'furniture': ["table", "chair", "lamp"],
    'myid': ['1-12', '0-11', '2-12'],
    'clothing': ["pants", "shoes", "socks"]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
ddf_1 = spark.createDataFrame(df_1)

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)
ddf_2 = spark.createDataFrame(df_2)
```

I imagine a function something like this:

```
def func(df_1, df_2, column_1, column_2):
    if df_1.column_1 != df_2.column_2:
       return df_1.withColumn('is_fact', False)
    else:
        return df_1.withColumn('is_fact', True)
    return df_1
```

The desired output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see: [ask], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a left outer join between the 2 dataframes on the `my_id` column and use a simple case statement to derive the `is_fine` column, as shown below,

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

ddf_1.join(ddf_2, ddf_1.myid == ddf_2.myid, 'left')\
.withColumn('is_fine', F.when(ddf_2.myid.isNull(), False).otherwise(True))\
.select(ddf_1['fruits'], ddf_1['myid'], ddf_1['meat'], 'is_fine').show()
```

Output:

```
+------+----+-------+-------+
|fruits|myid|   meat|is_fine|
+------+----+-------+-------+
|cherry|3-13|chicken|  false|
|apples|1-12|    pig|   true|
|banana|2-12|    cow|   true|
+------+----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you @noufel13 this worked great for me. The only thing that I changed was to make the column select statement more generic as this is fake data and I usually have a lot of columns to select and can not hard code each one individually. You can find the code below

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of Spark SQL for this kind of problems:

```
query = """
select ddf_1.*,
case 
    when ddf_1.myid = ddf_2.myid  then True
    else False 
end as is_fine
from ddf_1 left outer join ddf_2 
on ddf_1.myid = ddf_2.myid
"""

display(spark.sql(query))
```

Here's the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTUdq.png)

Comment: I would do 'CASE WHEN ddf_2.myid IS NULL' instead of 'when ddf_1.myid = ddf_2.myid'

Comment: I get a  Table or view not found: ddf_1; line 8 pos 5 exception.

Comment: you need to convert dataframe to a temp view before `ddf_1.createOrReplaceTempView("ddf_1")`

Answer (score 0):

```
#left join ddf2 on ddf1
result = (ddf_1.join(ddf_2, ddf_1.myid == ddf_2.myid, how='left')\
          #create is_fine column
          .withColumn('is_fine', F.when(ddf_2.myid.isNull(), False).otherwise(True)))\
          #select all columns from ddf_1, the new column is_fine and show
          .select(ddf_1["*"], "is_fine").show()
```